# Sequential Aggregation Model - data.frame

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to design an aggregation process. I try to avoid the problems caused by 'expand.grid' (i.e., excessive vector length).

I have designed a dataframe DATA. Initially I have to jointly apply a process to P1 and V1 and V2 and P2. Once executed, P1, P2, V1 y V2 have to be removed, and the process output (two vectors: P12 and V12) added to the dataframe DATA, and again reapply the process to vectors V12 and P12 and V3 and P3. So in succession until V3 and P3 have been removed, V123 and P123 have been added, and reapplied the process to V123 and P123 and V4 and P4. The data frame is filled with NA or 0.

It is important to note that I usually work with n vectors (Pi) and n vectors (Vi).

Dataframe DATA:

```
    P1 P2 P3 P4          V1     V2          V3   V4
  1  0  0  0  0  0.34505340 0.9498 0.958886346 0.88
  2  1  1  1  1  0.11640585 0.0338 0.012040961 0.04
  3  2  2  2  2  0.09746205 0.0164 0.009259039 0.08
  4  3  0  3  0  0.11484475 0.0000 0.019813654 0.00
  5  4  0  0  0  0.32623395 0.0000 0.000000000 0.00
```

An example output:

```
      P12     V12    
 1      0  0.1851 
 2      1  0.1419 
 3      2  0.1794 
 4      3  0.1395 
 5      4  0.3659 
 6      5 -0.0045 
 7      6 -0.0141
```

Kind regards,
majesus

Comment: Can you show an output sample data set? I am trying to understand what happens to P12 or V12 after your operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following with `dplyr` to incrementally mutate columns. I store the target varnames and the formulas in a string. This is just a simple example to illustrate the method. I assume your calculation is a bit more complex.

```
df <- data.frame(p1 = 0:4
                 ,p2 = c(0,1,2,0,0)
                 ,p3 = c(0:3,0)
                 ,p4 = c(0,1,2,0,0)
                 ,v1 = rnorm(5)
                 ,v2 = rnorm(5)
                 ,v3 = rnorm(5)
                 ,v5 = rnorm(5))

library(dplyr)
var <- sapply(2:4,function(x) paste0('p',paste0(1:x, collapse="")))

form <- sapply(2:4,function(x) paste0("p",paste0(1:(x-1),collapse = ""),"*","p",x))

df %>% mutate_(.dots=setNames(form, var))
```

string vectors:

```
> var
[1] "p12"   "p123"  "p1234"
> form
[1] "p1*p2"   "p12*p3"  "p123*p4"
```

result:

```
p1 p2 p3 p4         v1         v2         v3         v5 p12 p123 p1234
 0  0  0  0  0.6901867  0.6365963  0.3526106 -0.8348200   0    0     0
 1  1  1  1  0.1530939  0.8553939  1.2160768  3.1494818   1    1     1
 2  2  2  2  1.2732477 -0.3102100  1.2538673  0.8904290   4    8    16
 3  0  3  0  0.9067448  0.7085275 -1.0328784  0.1979246   0    0     0
 4  0  0  0 -0.1388101  0.1275527  1.6018554  0.4335777   0    0     0
```

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your response. My task is to jointly apply the process on the variables Pi and Vi, not only on Pi. Also, it is not easy for me to program the process in 'function' mode. Can I use 'while' or 'for-loop'?

Comment: The answer is just an illustration. In fact it is a loop. the `mutate_` command is evaluating every calculation in the vector `form` sequentially. Thus you need to make sure that in this vector there is also a calculation for v12 v123 and v1234.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much.